# How do I put a specific user choice into a list from a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get my python code so it happens like this
Imports Register.txt [Done]
Now loops it and asks the user which variable it wants to go to
following code is:

```
print("Registration System")
print("Make sure their is atleast one name in register!")
input("Enter any key to continue ")
with open ("register.txt", "r") as register:
    registers = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in register]
    for pop in registers:
        print(pop)
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what should happen on each iteration.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second part. It's not really clear what you want to do.

Comment: Hey, What I want to do is After opening register.txt it'll ask each item in the list where it wants to go for example, if test123 was the first in the list, It would ask: Where would you like to put this? and e.g Enter 1 to send it to set1, enter 2 to send it to set 2, etc. Then will do so for the next item in the list

Comment: Ask them where they want to go? Go where? What does that mean? Set 1 and set 2? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right you can try this:

```
print("Registration System")
print("Make sure their is atleast one name in register!")
input("Enter any key to continue ")
set1 = set()
set2 = set()
with open("register.txt", "r") as register:
    registers = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in register]
    for pop in registers:
        print(pop)
        choice = input(
            'Where would you like it to go? (Enter 1 - set1, enter 2 - set2)')
        if choice == '1':
            set1.add(pop)
        elif choice == '2':
            set2.add(pop)

print(set1)
print(set2)
```

Comment: Thank you! Been trying to do this for a few hours

Comment: @PaulBrennan, I am glad to help you. You can accept the answer now to close the question.